# Record unique views on the web with Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm building a React web app, where users can create 'content'. The content is displayed when a certain URL is visited, e.g.: **https://myapp.com/username/contentid**

The user doesn't have to be signed in to view the content.

My question is, how do I track unique views with Realtime firebase?

I don't necessarily need a code implementation, rather an idea/approach. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, you would need to enable your database to allow for writing capabilities from anonymous users. From there, write to the database when the site is first opened. You could store this information in a variety of different ways, I would recommend posting a timestamp and seeing total unique views by counting the total amount of timestamps uploaded. It may also be important to store locally, via Cookies, if the user has been to the site already. If they have, don't write.

Comment: Thanks! But what if the same person views the site multiple times? I want it so that every day one person (a device) could only contribute one unique view.

Comment: The aspect about cookies should work for that as it will prevent the same user from viewing it on the same browser over and over again. You can reset it after a day if you'd like locally in the browser.